# Make zsh aliases work with a prefixed command

Tags: zsh, variable-expansion

Some commands manipulate the environment in some way and then call another command. For example, `xargs <command> <args>` takes arguments via standard input and appends them to the end of the args list, then runs `<command>` with those arguments.

Separately, I can define aliases in my zsh configuration. For example,

```
alias ll='ls -al'
```

means that I can type `ll` at the command line and ZSH will expand that to `ls -al`.

However, I can't use the two in combination. If I write `echo Documents | xargs ll` I get:

```
ll: command not found
```

Is there a way to instruct ZSH to expand aliases after the command in question? E.g. "if the first command is xargs, expand anything else you see afterwards."

Answer (score 1):

You could define a global alias:

```
alias -g ll='ls -al'
```

Be aware, though, that this would expand `ll` *anywhere* it is found as a distinct word, not just as the command argument to commands like `xargs`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Aliasing)

> Every eligible word in the shell input is checked to see if there is an alias defined for it. If so, it is replaced by the text of the alias if it is in command position (if it could be the first word of a simple command), or if the alias is global. **If the replacement text ends with a space, the next word** in the shell input is always eligible for purposes of **alias expansion**. An alias is defined using the alias builtin; **global aliases** may be defined using the -g option to that builtin.

Global alias is not good, since global aliased `ll` in `echo ll` will be expanded.

Your first option is to `alias xargs='xargs '`, the extra space will cause the word following xargs to expand.

But there is still a problem. For example, `mv` is often aliased to `nocorrect mv`, so `xargs mv` will complain `nocorrect: No such file or directory`

My solution is to use the following snippet to make it a function.

```sh
function alias_unwrapper {
    local sudo="$1"
    if [[ ! -x "$sudo" ]]; then
       echo "$sudo not found"; return;
    fi
    local cmd=(${(s: :)aliases[$2]}); # let cmd be array of command and arguments
    (($#cmd)) || cmd=($2)             # if cmd has no aliases, use array of a single element
    while (( $#cmd > 0 )) && [[ $cmd[1] == "nocorrect" || $cmd[1] == "noglob" ]]; do
        shift cmd;         # remove beginning garbage
    done
    local args=(${cmd:1}); # origin params of alias
    args+=(${@:3})         # additional params after alias
    $sudo ${cmd[1]} $args        # unwrap the args array
}


function xargs {
    local XARGS=/usr/bin/xargs
    alias_unwrapper $XARGS $@
}
```

I myself use the code above to expand `sudo`, `watch`, `parallel`, etc.